# how to keep the values in the extras persistent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have three activities, ActA,ActB and ActC. ActA starts ActB using startActivity(intent), and that intent contains some double values in the extras as follows:

```
intent.putExtra(KEY_JAERLICHE_KOST, mHashVersPricing.get(position).getKostenProJahr());//double value
    intent.putExtra(KEY_MONATLICHE_KOST, mHashVersPricing.get(position).getKostenProMonat());//double value
```

when ActB starts, I can receive the values of the variable contained in the extras and they are correct.

the problem is, when ActB starts ActC and i go back to ActB from ActC. in this case, the code below will be executed as well but the values of the variables will be zero which is wrong.

what i want to do is to keep the values of the variables contained in the extras remains unchanged even when i navigate back from ActC to ActB.

please let me know how to make the values in the extras persistent when i navigate back to ActB

**code in ActB for receiving the extras in the intent**:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null && intent.hasExtra(Vers.KEY_JAERLICHE_KOST) && intent.hasExtra(VersicherungsListeActivity.KEY_MONATLICHE_KOST)) {
            this.mJärlicheKost = (double) extras.get(Vers.KEY_JAERLICHE_KOST);
            this.mMonatlicheKost = (double) extras.get(Vers.KEY_MONATLICHE_KOST);
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "extras is null or the specified keys are not associated to it");

            Log.e(TAG, "mJärlicheKost: " + mJärlicheKost);//this is zero when i navigate from ActC to ActB which is wrong
            Log.e(TAG, "mMonatlicheKost: " + mMonatlicheKost);//this is zero when i navigate from ActC to ActB which is wrong
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "intent is null");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use StartActivityForResult to call your activities, if you want to get results, when you are returning back to your caller activity to called activity.

Comment: why should i use StratActivityForResult?

Comment: because when you ActB starts ActC and you go back to ActB from ActC. in that case, you are getting wrong results. Perform your operation on On activityresult to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In standart launch mode, after switching to ActC, the ActB will be created from scratch (with no your intent data)

You need to change launch mod of ActB

```
<activity android:name="ActB" launchMode="singleTop" ... />
```

In that case you'll receive old ActB